# What bibliography style should I use in a presentation?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am using authoryear (from biblatex) style for articles. However, for beamer presentations, this style is not useful. Indeed, the complete references are cited at the end of the presentation ; so I have severals slides with only references. I will not take 5 min at the end of my presentation to allow everyone to read my bibliography (it makes no sense).

If I decide to use a verbose style which will put references in footnotes, I have other problems : Many footnotes eats the space and they are too tiny to allow a good reading...

Does someone is aware of a bibliography style designed for beamer presentation?

Comment: It is probably best to go with a slightly more verbose Author/Year/Title style in the presentation itself and have a printed bibliography handout ready. Also: Do not cite too many references, only the necessary ones.

Comment: just  manually type author and two digit year. people can find any paper hence it's a habit not a requirement to put bibliography in a presentation. To be honest noone cares otherwise they ask about it.

Comment: The `beamer` user guide is quite adamant in its claim that it's best *not* to include a bibliography -- of any kind -- in a `beamer` presentation...

Comment: @Mico ok but it is sometimes hard to reconcile this claim and academics needs.

Comment: @ppr - I've sat through countless academic presentations, and I can't honestly remember a single instance of (i) the presenter(s) *not* providing a bibliography and me thinking, "gosh, they really ought to have provided a bibliography as part of the presentation", or (ii) [rather infrequently!] the presenter(s) providing a bibliography and me thinking, "wow, now this is really helpful that I'm being shown a bibliography." Is it common practice in your field to provide a bibliography section as part of a presentation?

Comment: Are the references important? If so, are there more than one or two? If there are one or two important ones, leave them on the final slide while you take questions. If there are more than that, use a handout. Even if there are only one or two, a handout maybe better. If they are unimportant, cut them. People who want them can still ask. Whichever you do, work attributions into the text of the slides so that you are giving due credit but don't include the references in the slides themselves. (Author-year is not terrible. A page number is OK if you are teaching and this is an assigned text.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the template, I often use. It is essentially `beamer`s default, but with a triangle as list symbol instead of the document icon.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{literature.bib}
@book{van2012latex,
  title={\LaTeX\ and Friends},
  author={{van Dongen}, R.C.},
  isbn={978-3-642-23816-1},
  lccn={2011945089},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@book{mittelbach2004latex,
  title={The \LaTeX\ Companion},
  author={Mittelbach, F. and Goossens, M.},
  isbn={978-0-133-38764-3},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Pearson Education}
}

@book{knuth2004texbook,
  title={The \TeX book},
  author={Knuth, D.E.},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[triangle]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Further Reading}
    \raggedright
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{literature}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]